# netty http request getContent sometime give a headers in body

Tags: java, http, http-headers, netty, nio

I'm using netty in client mode using ClientBootstrap. When i'm trying to recieve a message most times it works fine and return me only a body, but sometimes( the server always return same response) i get a headers inside content, when i call a message.getContent():

```
Content-type: text/xml;charset=windows-1251
Content-length: 649
Connection: keep-alive

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<response>
  <status>
    <code>0</code>
  </status>
  <detail>
```

Obviously it should be only body of http request.. And when it return header part in a  body, the body part itself is a cutted by the size of the headers.

Here is my PipileniFactory:

```
public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = pipeline();
    if (isSecure) {
        SSLContext clientContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        clientContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{DUMMY_TRUST_MANAGER}, null);
        SSLEngine engine = clientContext.createSSLEngine();
        engine.setUseClientMode(true);
        pipeline.addLast("ssl", new SslHandler(engine));
    }

    pipeline.addLast("codec", new HttpClientCodec());
    pipeline.addLast("aggregator", new HttpChunkAggregator(1048576));
    pipeline.addLast("timeout", new ReadTimeoutHandler(timer, timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
    pipeline.addLast("handler", ibConnectorHandler);
    return pipeline;
}
```

And here is messageReceived from ibConnectorHandler:

```
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) throws Exception {
    logger.info("Received");

    HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) e.getMessage();
    ChannelBuffer resContent = response.getContent();
    byte[] content = null;
    if (resContent.readable()) {
        content = Arrays.copyOf(resContent.array(), resContent.readableBytes());
        logger.debug(Arrays.toString(req.getParams().toArray()) + "----------" + new String(content));
    }

}
```

i'm using netty 3.5.8.

UPD
When all is correct the resContent is instanceof org.jboss.netty.buffer.BigEndianHeapChannelBuffer. And when it shows header resContent is instanceof org.jboss.netty.buffer.SlicedChannelBuffer.  So there is a problem when netty used a org.jboss.netty.buffer.SlicedChannelBuffer for a content of http message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "Arrays.copyOf(resContent.array(), resContent.readableBytes())" you don't respect the offset in the array. You need to also hand in the the offset which you can get from ChannelBuffer.arrayOffset() + ChannelBuffer.readerIndex();

See: http://static.netty.io/3.5/api/org/jboss/netty/buffer/ChannelBuffer.html#arrayOffset()

Comment: Yep, thanks, that was issue. I finished using resContent.getBytes which respect offset.
Btw, this code was working fine in netty 3.5.1

Comment: It was working fine in 3.5.1 because we made some optimization which will safe you from some byte-copies and so speed up things. in 3.5.1 we always created a new buffer for the content and copied things over.